# Which trigonometric identities involve trigonometric functions?

Tags: trigonometry, functional-equations

Once upon a time, when Wikipedia was only three-and-a-half years old and most people didn't know what it was, the article titled [functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation) gave the identity
$$
\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta = 1
$$
as an example of a functional equation.  In [this edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Functional_equation&diff=4565145&oldid=4565118) in July 2004, my summary said "I think the example recently put here is really lousy, because it's essentially just an algebraic equation in two variables."  (Then some subsequent edits I did the same day brought the article to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Functional_equation&oldid=4577672) state, and much further development of the article has happened since then.)

The fact that it's really only an algebraic equation in two variables, $x^2+y^2=1$, makes it a lousy example of a functional equation.  It doesn't really involve $x$ and $y$ as functions of $\theta$, since any other parametrization of the circle would have satisfied the same equation.  In a sense, that explains why someone like Norman Wildberger can do all sorts of elaborate things with trigonometry without ever using trigonometric functions.

**But some** trigonometric identities do involve trigonometric functions, e.g.
$$
\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)=\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_2
$$
$$
\sec(\theta_1+\cdots+\theta_n) = \frac{\sec\theta_1\cdots\sec\theta_n}{e_0-e_2+e_4-e_6+\cdots}
$$
where $e_k$ is the $k$th-degree elementary symmetric polynomial in $\tan\theta_1,\ldots,\tan\theta_n$.  These are good examples of satisfaction of functional equations.

So at this point I wonder whether **all** trigonometric identities that do seem to depend on which parametrization of the circle is chosen involve adding or subtracting the arguments and no other operations.  In some cases the addition or subtraction is written as a condition on which the identity depends, e.g.
$$
\text{If }x+y+z=\pi\text{ then }\tan x+\tan y+\tan z = \tan x\tan y\tan z.
$$

**QUESTION:** Do **all** trigonometric identities that **do** involve trigonometric functions, in the sense that they are good examples of satisfaction of functional equations by trigonometric functions, get their non-triviality as such examples only from the addition or subtraction of arguments?  Or is there some other kind?  And if there is no other kind, can that be proved?

**Postscript:** Wikipedia's [list of trigonometic identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) is more interesting reading than you might think.  It has not only the routine stuff that you learned in 10th grade, but also some exotic things that probably most mathematicians don't know about.  It was initially created in September 2001 by Axel Boldt, who was for more than a year the principal author of nearly all of Wikipedia's mathematics articles.

Comment: Do you count half-angle formulas ($\cos(x/2)=\sqrt{(1+\cos x)/2}$) as addition/subtraction of arguments?

Comment: @GerryMyerson : I think one would have to count it that way.  It's the same as $\cos w = \sqrt{(1+\cos(w+w))/2}$.

Comment: OK, then, how about $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(x/2^k)=(\sin x)/x$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson : $x_2+x_2=x_1$, $x_3+x_3=x_2$, etc., and then $\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos(x_k/2) = (\sin x)/x$.

Comment: If we're going to have "identities" with infinitely many terms, how about $$\cos(t \sin(x)) = J_0(t) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty J_{2k}(t) \cos(2kx)$$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael : This looks like a counterexample to my guess.  So a question is whether any such counterexample needs to have infinitely many terms?  Or whether it must have something complicated like $k\mapsto J_{2k}(t)$?  (One needn't go into $t\mapsto J_{2k}(t)$ since one would have a separate identity for each value of $t$ separately.)

Comment: PS: I see no reason not to allow infinitely many terms.  At least not yet.

Comment: PPS: The aspect of it that qualifies it as a counterexample, at least to the simplest interpretation of my guess, is the left side---definitely not the right side.  The right side is innocent.

Comment: If we allow angles and lengths of the sides we have in a triangle e.g. the law of sines.

Comment: @AméricoTavares : But that involves adding, i.e. the sum of the three angles is $\pi$, just as in the case I mentioned that says the sum of the tangents equals the product of the tangents if the sum of the three angles is $\pi$.

Comment: My rather trivial point is that instead of having an identity in the trigonometric functions of angles only (as in $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta = 1$ or in $\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)=\sin\theta_1\cos\theta_2+\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_2$) we also have the lengths of sides.

Comment: I'm not sure lengths of sides add a lot, unless you're dealing with polygons not inscribable in a sphere.  The law of cosines says $a^2+b^2-2ab\cos C = c^2$.  But if the circumscribed circle has unit diameter, then $a$, $b$, and $c$ are respectively $\sin A$, $\sin B$, and $\sin C$, and the identity says that if $A+B+C=\pi$ then $\sin^2 A+\sin^2 B - 2\sin A\sin B\cos C = \sin^2 C$.

Comment: Actually it occurs to me that the law of sines would still have some substance: it would say that if the circumscribed circle has unit diameter, then $a$, $b$, and $c$ are respectively $\sin A$, $\sin B$, and $\sin C$.

Comment: @AméricoTavares : "not inscribable in a sphere".  Sorry---I meant not inscribable in a circle.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You are right.

Comment: How would you classify these? (It's Daviddaved@Wiki, thanks 4 your help there):http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389225/a-matrix-w-integer-eigenvalues-and-trigonometric-identity

Comment: @Daved : Hello.  At first glance that looks to me like something that doesn't depend on the fact that the circle is parametrized by arc length rather than in some other way.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : Months ago I added your identity $\cos(t \sin(x))$ $= J_0(t) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty$ $J_{2k}(t) \cos(2kx)$ to Wikipedia's "list of trigonometric identities", and now I'm being asked if I can cite a source for it.  Any ideas?

Comment: It comes via Fourier series from the integral representation of the Bessel functions,
$$ J_n(t) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \exp(i n x - i t \sin(x))\; dx$$

Comment: Ah, here it is: Abramowitz & Stegun formula 9.1.42.

Comment: @RobertIsrael : Perfect!  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta = 1$$
can be rewritten as functional equation:
$$\sin^2\theta+\sin^2(\theta+\pi/2) = 1.$$

Comment: But maybe the "trigonometric identity involving trigonometric functions" in this instance is $\cos\theta=\sin(\theta+\pi/2)$, without the Pythagorean identity.

Comment: But $\cos\theta=\sin(\theta+\pi/2)$ is very trivial and uninteresting. The relation of trigonometric functions with the Pythagorean identity is interesting.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, interesting but paywalled: http://universitypublishingonline.org/maa/chapter.jsf?bid=CBO9780883859667&cid=CBO9780883859667A035.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, also interesting: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-096-02/S0002-9939-1986-0818470-6/S0002-9939-1986-0818470-6.pdf.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, the question is how uniquely we can determine trigonometric functions using functional equations. First thing is together with a strong enough functional equation we always need a some sort of "smoothness" condition. For example consider the system $$\begin{cases}
f(x+y)=f(x)g(y)+g(x)f(y) \\
g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)-f(x)f(y)
\end{cases}$$

Under any assumption sufficient for Cauchy functional equation we can deduce that it has a [solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641416/functional-equations-leading-to-sine-and-cosine) involving sine-and-cosine, but there are wildly discontinuous solutions one can construct using a Hamel bases of rationals over reals.

Next, since the set of all interesting functional equations is too big to consider, we can focus on somewhat special class called algebraic [Addition theorems.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition_theorem) For example $$h(x+y)=h(x)\sqrt{1-(h(y))^2}+\sqrt{1-(h(x))^2}h(y).$$ It is a theorem by Weierstrass that characterize all such meromorphic functions as either rational or [periodic](http://www.math.ust.hk/%7Emachiang/5030/notes/Chap5_a.pdf) depending on the singularity type of $h$ at $\infty.$ You can see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.6471.pdf) for more details. Since the Jacobi's impossibility theorem of triply periodic meromorphic functions, we can find all of them explicitly. Roughly these are:

- trigonometric functions (including hyperbolic, and exponential functions)
- elliptic functions (I think of theses as some sort of generalized trigonometric functions, and I am not completely wrong as the theory of Jacobi elliptic functions can [develop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCXItCajCyo) entirely analogous to trigonometry)
- rational functions (in particular polynomials).

So yes!, under some reasonable assumptions, algebraic addition theorems recover a generalized class of trigonometric functions. Here being meromorphic is important otherwise we should include algebraic functions (and possibly more!). Alternatively, I will roughly sketch a proof to convince you that any complex differentiable function  with an algebraic addition theorem is the inverse of a certain kind of [integral.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_integral) Let $\varphi$ be an analytic function (on some domain of $\mathbb{C}$) with an addition theorem, then there is a polynomial $G$ with constant coefficients satisfying $$G(\zeta, \eta, \theta) =0,\tag1$$ where $\zeta=\varphi(z), \eta=\varphi(w)=$ and $\theta=\varphi(w+z).$ Since $\zeta$ and $\eta$ are independent variables, by considering total derivatives of $G$ with respect to them gives: $$\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial \zeta}\dfrac{d \zeta}{d z}+\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial \theta}\dfrac{d \theta}{d z}=\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial \eta}\dfrac{d \eta}{d w}+\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial \theta}\dfrac{d \theta}{d w}=0.$$ Also we know that $\dfrac{d \theta}{d z}=\dfrac{d \theta}{d w},$ and consequently $$\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial \zeta}\dfrac{d \zeta}{d z}-\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial \eta}\dfrac{d \eta}{d w}=0.\tag2$$ If $\theta$ does not appear in $\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial \zeta}, \dfrac{\partial G}{\partial \eta},$ this lase equation is an expression that contains only  $\zeta, \dfrac{d \zeta}{d z}, \eta$ and $\dfrac{d \eta}{d w}.$ On the other hand, even if they contain $\theta$ we can eliminate it using both $(1), (2)$ to obtain a polynomial relation with constant coefficients $$H\left(\zeta, \dfrac{d \zeta}{d z}, \eta, \dfrac{d \eta}{d w}\right)=0.$$ Since this is true for all $z, w$ in the domain, we can evaluate $v$ at some specific point to obtain a first order differential equation $\tilde{H}\left(\zeta, \dfrac{d \zeta}{d z}\right)=0.$ If this evaluation of $H$ vanish in all its coefficient, we can try different values of $w$ until we find a non-zero equation $\tilde{H}.$ We can solve this equation in terms of an algebraic function $K$ such that $\dfrac{d \zeta}{d z}=K(\zeta),$ and hence after separating variables $$z-z_0=\displaystyle\int_{\zeta_0}^{\zeta}\dfrac{d\zeta}{K(\zeta)}.$$
where $\varphi(z_0)=\zeta_0$ are appropriate constants. Then the addition thereom of $\varphi$ can be rewritten as $$\displaystyle\int_{\varphi(z_0)}^{\zeta}\dfrac{d\zeta}{K(\zeta)}+\displaystyle\int_{\varphi(z_0)}^{\eta}\dfrac{d\zeta}{K(\zeta)}=\displaystyle\int_{\varphi(z_0)}^{\theta}\dfrac{d\zeta}{K(\zeta)}.$$

You can find the original argument of this algorithm in [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=GDYNAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Hancock+elliptic+functions&cd=1#v=onepage&q&f=false) with all the details and much more. For example to what I described here:
\begin{array}{|l|c|r|}
\zeta=\varphi(z) & \theta & \tilde{H} \\
\hline
\sin z & \zeta\sqrt{1-\eta^2}+\eta\sqrt{1-\zeta^2} & \left(\dfrac{d \zeta}{d z}\right)^2+\zeta^2-1 \\
\tan z & \dfrac{\zeta+\eta}{1-\zeta\eta} & \dfrac{d \zeta}{d z}-\zeta^2-1\\
\sec z & \dfrac{\zeta\eta}{1-\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}\sqrt{1-\eta^2}} & \left(\dfrac{d \zeta}{d z}\right)^2-\zeta^2(\zeta^2-1) 
\end{array}

I am too lazy to continue this for other trigonometric and hyperbolic functions. In the next [simplest case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) $K(\zeta)=K(\zeta, \sqrt{P(\zeta)})$ is a rational function, where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $3$ or $4$ with no repeated roots, we recover the  Jacobian elliptic functions. Similar computations can carry on for some other elliptic functions, in particular for [lemniscate functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149316/trigonometry-with-alternative-parametrizations-of-the-circle/149445#149445) mentioned in this solution to one of your question.

Answer (score 2):

All the trigonometric identities can be derived from the properties of complex number multiplication.

The point on the unit circle at angle t in radians, as measured from the positive $x$-axis
is $(\cos(t) + i \sin(t))$

The distance of this point from the origin is 1 because it is on the unit circle. Thus the magnitude of $( \cos(t) + i \sin(t) )$ is $1$ and this leads immediately to the identity

$$( \cos(t))^2 + ( \sin(t))^2 = 1$$

The sum of angle formulas follow immediately from the rule that to multiply two complex numbers you add their angles and multiply their magnitudes.

$$( \cos(t_1) + i \sin(t_1) ) \cdot ( \cos(t_2) + i \sin(t_2))$$

$$= \cos(t_1 + t_2) + i \sin (t_1 + t_2)
(\cos (t_1) \cos(t_2) - \sin(t_1 ) \sin(t_2) )
+ i ( \cos(t_1) \sin(t_2) + \sin(t_1) \cos(t_2) )
= \cos( t_1 + t_2) + i \sin(t_1 + t_2)$$

Separating real and imaginary components,

$$\cos(t_1) \cos(t_2) - \sin(t_1) \sin(t_2) = \cos(t_1 + t_2)$$

$$\cos(t_1) \sin(t_2) + \sin(t_1) \cos(t_2) = \sin(t_1 + t_2)$$

Comment: Well, all this is standard stuff that I've known since I was in high school, but it doesn't really answer the question actually asked.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> So at this point I wonder whether **all** trigonometric identities that do seem to depend on which parametrization of the circle is chosen involve adding or subtracting the arguments and no other operations.

and asked

> **QUESTION:** Do **all** trigonometric identities that **do**
> involve trigonometric functions, in the sense that they are good examples
> of satisfaction of functional equations by trigonometric functions, get
> their non-triviality as such examples only from the addition or subtraction of arguments?  Or is there some other kind?  And if there is
> no other kind, can that be proved?

I think that functional equations which are trigonometric identities
need not have any connection with the circle. I think that here is a
simple example.

**Theorem:** Suppose $\,f(z)\,$ is an odd $\,(f(z)=-f(-z))\,$
analytic function with a power series expansion of

$$ f(z) = a_1\frac{z^1}{1!} + a_3\frac{z^3}{3!} + a_5\frac{z^5}{5!}
 + \cdots \tag{1} $$

and suppose that it satisfies the functional equation for all complex $\,z\,$

$$ 0 = f(z)f(3z) + f(z)^2 - f(2z)^2. \tag{2} $$

Then the coefficient sequence $\,a_1,\,a_3,\,a_5,\,\dots\,$ forms a
geometric progression which implies that

$$ f(z) = c_1\,\sinh(c_2\,z),\;\; a_k = c_1c_2^k \;\;
 \text{ if $k$ odd}. \tag{3} $$

This single functional equation $(2)$ is merely one special case of
an infinite number of functional equations derived from the two
variable functional equation

$$ 0 = f(w-z)f(w+z) + f(z)^2 - f(w)^2. \tag{4} $$

This equation, in turn, is only one of a number of multivariable
homogeneous functional equations of a constrained class that has
solutions as in equation $(3)$. Also, some of these equations have general solutions which are
[Weierstrass sigma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_functions)
but have trigonometric sine as special cases. For example,

$$ 0 = f(w-z)^3 f(w+z) + f(z)^3 f(z-2w) - f(w)^3 f(2z-w). \tag{5} $$

Also, some of these equations have general solutions which are
[Jacobi Elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions) such as
$\,\text{sn}(z,m),\,\text{sc}(z,m),\,\text{sd}(z,m)\,$ but have
trigonometric sine and tangent as special cases. For example,

$$ 0 \!=\! f(w) f(z) f(w\!+\!z) \!+\! f(w) f(w\!-\!z) f(z\!-\!2w)
   \!+\! f(2w) f(w\!+\!z) f(w\!-\!z) \!+\! f(2w) f(z) f(z\!-\!2w).
  \tag{6} $$

Some of these functional equations which arise from algebraic
identities are contained in my web page
["Special Algebraic Identities"](https://grail.eecs.csuohio.edu/%7Esomos/ident04.txt)
which contains over 700 identities.

I am not sure how to interpret your question about

> get their non-triviality as such examples only from the addition
> or subtraction of arguments?

because I don't know what you mean by "non-triviality". Please try
to be more explicit in your question. Give a few examples and also
some counterexamples.