# A matrix w/integer eigenvalues and trigonometric identity

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boolean-algebra, natural-numbers

Any intuition and/or rigorous arguments on the proofs of the following statements would be appreciated:

Let $n$ be a natural number. 
(a) Consider the following Toeplitz/circulant symmetric matrix:

$$
\Lambda_{kl} = \begin{cases}\frac{2n(n+1)}{3}, & k = l, \\[6pt]
\frac{-1}{1-\cos\frac{2\pi(k-l)}{2n+1}}, & k \ne l,\end{cases}
$$

where $k,l = 1,2, \ldots, 2n+1$.

Prove that its eigenvalues are natural numbers(!)

$$2n, 4n-2, 6n-6, \ldots, n(n+1)$$

with multiplicity $2$ and $0$ w/multiplicity $1$.

(b) Find a formula for the right signs in the following trigonometric identity

$$
\tan\left(\frac{l\pi}{2n+1}\right) = 2\sum_{k=1}^n (\pm)\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right),\qquad l = 1,2,\ldots, n.
$$

and show that the signs are uniquely determined in the case of prime $2n+1$.

The problems (that are formulated to be self-contained) arise from discrete approximation of continuous inverse boundary problem (see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/On_2D_Inverse_Problems for background) and the statements were formulated w/computer help.

Comment: A tip for (b): Multiply through by $\cos(l\pi/(2n+1))$, and invoke the identity $2\sin A \cos B = \sin(A+B)+\sin(A-B)$, so that the right-hand side becomes $$\sum_k \; \pm \left(\;\sin\frac{(k+l)\pi}{2n+1}+\sin\frac{(k-l)\pi}{2n+1}\;\right)$$ Somewhere amid all those sines, you'll get an instance equivalent to $\sin(l\pi/(2n+1))$. Make *that* pair's "$\pm$" a "$+$"; then, ignore the $\sin(l\pi/(2n+1))$ part of that pair (as it matches the left-hand side), and set about getting the remaining sines to cancel.

Comment: Seems like a good step, but how can we cancel the remaining sines?  Also, can we see that $2n+1$ being a prime plays a role?

Comment: I've just played with a few small examples. If the "other" sine in that initial "$+$" pair isn't itself zero, I've been able to find a matching sine in another pair to cancel it (with an appropriate "$\pm$" choice), and then the other sine from *that* pair leads me to a matching sine in *another* pair, and so forth. (Primality may help show that that path from that initial sine is unique.) When that other sine in the initial pair *is* itself zero, matching sines don't seem to cancel each other; the cancellation is more subtle. But, again, I've just played with a few small examples.

Comment: The ways in which people use TeX on this site are sometimes quite baffling.  Daved: Why use a "\displaystyle" in your piecewise definition of $\Lambda_{k\ell}$ instead of an actual _display_, and why use the \mbox{} construction in "cases" instead of alignment tabs?  (I altered both and did some other TeX improvements.)

Comment: Was not sure how these work and just used a template. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you seen [this article](http://www1.american.edu/academic.depts/cas/mathstat/People/kalman/pdffiles/circulant.pdf), by any chance?

Comment: @J.M. No, I have not, thank you it's very relevant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer to (a), but it may be a start. It also explains the repeated eigenvalues.

It is known that a circulant matrix is diagonalized by the Fourier matrix and the eigenvalues of a circulant matrix are given by the discrete Fourier transform of its first row. See chapter 3 of [here](http://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/toeplitz.pdf) for a detailed explanation.

Let $c_j$ be the first row your matrix. Given the definition of $\Lambda$, we have

$$
c_j = \begin{cases} 2n(n+1)/3, & j = 0 \\[6pt]
\frac{-1}{1-\cos(\frac{2\pi j}{2n+1})}, & j = 1, \dots, 2n \\
\end{cases}
$$

Let $\lambda_m$ be the eigenvalues of $\Lambda$. Then

$$ 
\begin{align}
\lambda_m &= \sum_{j=0}^{2n}c_j \exp \left( -\frac{2\pi imj}{2n+1} \right) \\
&= \frac{2n(n+1)}{3} + \sum_{j=1}^{2n} c_j \exp \left( -\frac{2\pi imj}{2n+1} \right), \qquad m = 0, \dots, 2n
\end{align}
$$

The imaginary part of this sum will vanish, so we're left with

$$
\lambda_m = \frac{2n(n+1)}{3} + \sum_{j=1}^{2n} \frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi jm}{2n+1})}{\cos(\frac{2\pi j}{2n+1})-1}
$$

A closed form evaluation for this sum will solve the problem. I don't have any headway on this, but here are two observations.

**Observation 1** $ \qquad \lambda_0 = 0$

*Proof*

$$
\begin{align}
\lambda_0 &= \frac{2n(n+1)}{3} + \sum_{j=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{\cos(\frac{2\pi j}{2n+1}) - 1}\\
&= \frac{2n(n+1)}{3} -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{2n} \csc^2(\frac{\pi j}{2n+1}) \\
&= \frac{2n(n+1)}{3} -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{3} ((2n+1)^2 -1) \\
&= \frac{2n(n+1)}{3} - \frac{1}{6} (4n^2 + 4n) \\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$

In the first equality above, I've used the double angle identity, $sin^2(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}(1-cos(2\theta))$, and in the second the identity $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} csc^2(\frac{k\pi}{n}) = \frac{1}{3}(n^2 - 1)$, see proof below.

**Observation 2** $\qquad \lambda_m = \lambda_{2n + 1 - m}$

*Proof*

$$
\lambda_m = \frac{2n(n+1)}{3} + \sum_{j=1}^{2n} \frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi jm}{2n+1})}{\cos(\frac{2\pi j}{2n+1})-1} 
$$

$$
\lambda_{2n + 1 - m} = \frac{2n(n+1)}{3} + \sum_{j=1}^{2n} \frac{\cos(\frac{2\pi j(2n + 1 - m)}{2n+1})}{\cos(\frac{2\pi j}{2n+1})-1}
$$

The denominators in the fractions are the same. The result then follows by noticing that

$$
\begin{align}
\cos \left( \frac{2\pi j (2n + 1 -m )}{2n+1} \right) &= \cos \left( 2\pi j - \frac{2\pi j m}{2n+1} \right) \\
&= \cos \left( \frac{2\pi jm}{2n+1} \right)
\end{align}
$$

**Proof of** $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} csc^2(\frac{k\pi}{n}) = \frac{1}{3}(n^2 - 1)$

This proof follows exercise 8 in chapter 5 of Stromberg, *An Introduction to Classical Real Analysis*.

Begin with De Moivre's formula:
$$
\cos(nx) + i\sin(nx) = (\cos(x) + i\sin(x))^n
$$

Expanding the RHS via the Binomial Theorem gives $$ \cos(nx) + i\sin(nx) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\cos ^{n-k}(x) (i\sin(x))^k $$

Equate imaginary parts, the RHS is imaginary for $k$ odd, so set $k = 2j+1$

$$ \sin(nx) = \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor{\frac{n-1}{2}} \rfloor}(-1)^j\binom{n}{2j+1}\cos ^{n-2j-1}(x)\sin ^{2j+1}(x)$$

Setting $n = 2m+1$ and multiplying outside the sum by $\sin ^{2m}(x)$ and dividing on the inside gives

$$ \begin{align} \sin((2m+1)x) 
=& \sin ^{2m+1}(x)\sum_{j=0}^{m} (-1)^j\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}\cos ^{2(m-j)}(x)\sin ^{2(j-m)}(x) \\
=& \sin ^{2m+1}(x)\sum_{j=0}^{m} (-1)^j\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}(\cot ^2(x))^{m-j}
\end{align}
$$

Now $\sin((2m+1)x)$ has roots $x = \frac{k\pi}{{2m+1}}, k = 1, \dots, m$. This implies that the polynomial

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{m} (-1)^j\binom{2m+1}{2j+1}t^{m-j} $$ has roots $t = \cot ^2(\frac{k\pi}{2m+1}), k = 1 \dots m$. The sum of the roots of a polynomial of degree $m$ is equal to the negative of the coefficient of the $(m-1)$ degree term divided by the coefficient of the leading term. The leading term has coefficient $2m+1$, the $m-1$ degree term has coefficient $-\binom{2m+1}{3}$, thus the sum of the roots is $m(2m-1)/3$ and we have the identity

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{m}\cot^2 \left( \frac{k\pi}{2m+1} \right) = \frac{m(2m-1)}{3} $$

Making the substitution $\csc^2 \theta = 1 + \cot ^2 \theta$ gives

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{m} \csc^2 \left(\frac{k\pi}{2m+1} \right) = \frac{2}{3}m(m+1) \tag{1}$$

The statement to prove is $$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \csc^2 \left(\frac{k\pi}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{3}(n^2 - 1) \tag{2}$$

Making the substitution $n \rightarrow 2n + 1$, (2) is equivalent to $$ \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \csc^2 \left(\frac{k\pi}{2n + 1} \right) = \frac{4}{3}n(n+1) \tag{3}$$

Noticing that $\csc\left(\frac{k\pi}{2n+1}\right) = \csc\left(\frac{(2n+1-k)\pi}{2n+1}\right)$, we have that the sum over the first $n$ indices in $(3)$ equals the sum over last $n$ indices and thus that $(1)$ is equivalent to $(3)$. $\Box$

Comment: Observation 1: There is only a statement but no proof at the link. Observation 2: Does it follow from the fact that $\Lambda$ is symmetric?

Comment: @Daved: In general a symmetric circulant matrix will not obey Observation 2. The symmetry implies that the imaginary part of the Fourier transform vanishes (eigenvalues are real). I have edited the original post to include a proof of the identity. There are more powerful techniques available to handle generalizations of this identity, see [here](http://www.fq.math.ca/Papers1/44-3/quartgauthier03_2006.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Since (b) has been largely answered in the comments, I'll deal with (a) here.
It is the case here that there is a very simple (and otherwise useful and well-known) basis of eigenvectors. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $2n+1$-th root of unity. Our eigenvectors for $\Lambda$ will be the “cyclic” vectors, whose coordinates are successive powers of a root of unity :

$$
C_s=(\zeta^s,\zeta^{2s},\zeta^{3s}, \ldots ,\zeta^{(2n)s},1) \ (0 \leq s \leq 2n)
\tag{1}
$$

Let us compute all the coordinates of $\Lambda C_s$ ; in other words, we must 
compute the sum

$$
f(i,s)=\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1} \Lambda_{ij} \zeta^{sj} \tag{2}
$$

We have $f(i,s)=\frac{2}{3}n(n+1)\zeta^{si}+g(i,s)$, where

$$
g(i,s)=\sum_{j\neq i} \frac{\zeta^{sj}}{\frac{\zeta^{i-j}+\zeta^{j-i}}{2}-1}=
\sum_{t\neq 0} \frac{\zeta^{s(i+t)}}{\frac{\zeta^{-t}+\zeta^{t}}{2}-1}=
2\zeta^{si}\sum_{t=1}^{2n} \frac{(\zeta^t)^{s+1}}{(\zeta^{t}-1)^2}=
2\zeta^{si}\sum_{\eta\in U, \eta\neq 1} \frac{\eta^{s+1}}{(\eta-1)^2}
\tag{3}
$$

where $U$ is the set of all $(2n+1)$-th roots of unity. There are classical techniques to compute the RHS of (3) above ; see the answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396371/formula-for-the-sum-of-the-value-of-a-rational-function-over-roots-of-unity/396490#396490), where the final
formula obtained is

$$
\sum_{\eta\in U, \eta\neq 1} \frac{\eta^{s+1}}{(\eta-1)^2}
=\frac{6(2n+1-s)s-((2n+1)^2-1)}{12}=
\frac{s(2n+1-s)}{2}-\frac{n^2+n}{3}
 \tag{4}
$$

Combining (3) with (4), the terms in $\frac{n^2+n}{3}$ cancel out and we thus obtain

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1} \Lambda_{ij} \zeta^{sj}=s(2n+1-s)\zeta^{si} \tag{5}
$$

Or, to express things vectorially,

$$
\Lambda C_s=s(2n+1-s) C_s \tag{6}
$$

So $C_s$ is an eigenvector associated to the eigenvalue $s(2n+1-s)$ as wished.