# Functional equations leading to sine and cosine

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, continuity, functional-equations

This question is a possibly harder version of: [Find $g'(x)$ at $x=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640725/find-gx-at-x-0).

**Question.**  *Let $f,g :\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, such that
\begin{align}
f(x-y)=f(x)\, g(y)-f(y)\, g(x), \tag{1}\\
g(x-y)=g(x)\, g(y)+f(x)\, f(y), \tag{2}
\end{align}
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R} $. If $g$ is continuous at $x=0$ and not identically zero, then there exists an $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, such 
$$
f(x)=\sin \alpha x\quad\text{and}\quad g(x)=\cos \alpha x.
$$
Is there a pair of discontinuous $f$ and $g$ satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$*?

**Update.** If $\ell :\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a linear functional over $\mathbb Q$ (i.e., $\ell(qx+ry)=q\ell(x)+r\ell(y)$, for all $x,y\in\mathbb R$ and $q,r\in\mathbb Q$), then
$$
\sin\big(\ell(x)\big), \quad \cos\big(\ell(x)\big),
$$
satisfy $(1)$ and $(2)$. Discontinuous such functionals do exist, and they are obtainable
using Zorn's Lemma (equivalently the Axiom of Choice.) This takes care of the second question.

Comment: Unless your question is how to solve that without the axiom of choice, I don't see why the [axiom-of-choice] tag is relevant here.

Comment: Do you understand my previous comment? What does the question have to do with the axiom of choice?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Because the Axiom of Choice guarantees the existence of a linear functional $\ell$ which is not continuous, and hence the existence of $f,g$ satisfying these functional equations without being continuous!

Comment: So by this logic, every question in functional analysis should be tagged with the axiom of choice tag, because the axiom of choice guarantees the extension of functionals, and so on and so forth?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: This is not a Functional Analysis question. It is a question would be expected to be solved by high school math.

Comment: UGH. You completely ignored **everything** I wrote in my comment. The axiom of choice tag is for when the question is asking for the role of the axiom of choice in a problem. The fact that you can use the axiom of choice to solve this, doesn't mean that your question involves the axiom of choice. Similarly, the axiom of choice is involved in almost every functional analysis question, or in other questions from other fields which rely heavily on the axiom of choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Not just that. High school students (including IMO participants) do not know the Axiom of Choice, and it is possible that a problem for them (or an extension of such problem) requires the Axiom of Choice. Hence, it does not hurt to include it among the tags, if such is the case.

Comment: It does hurt, because it contributes to disorder of the barely functional tag system. It won't hurt using the general topology tag either, since you are talking about continuity and discontinuity. What about the geometry tags? Or complex analysis? What about logic, you do need to use mathematical logic to prove that your solution is correct... what about soft question? education? algebra-precalculus? What about all those tags? Why not use them too?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Apparently we agree that we disagree. Summarizing my opinion: if in a seeming extremely elementary problem (high school level) the Axiom of Choice is used, then it is appropriate to include it as a tag.

Comment: Please start a meta thread and ask whether or not this is appropriate. I think it's not.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I did that. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12582/when-do-we-include-axiom-of-choice-as-a-tag

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=1$, we also have $f(-y)=-f(y)$ and
\begin{align}
f(x+y)=f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x),\\
g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)-f(x)f(y).
\end{align}

Set $\psi(x)=g(x)+if(x)$. Then
\begin{align}
\psi(x+y)=g(x+y)+if(x+y)
&=g(x)g(y)-f(x)f(y)+i(f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x))\\[1ex]
&=(g(x)+if(x))(g(y)+if(y))\\[1ex]
&=\psi(x)\psi(y)
\end{align}
Thus $\psi$ is a homomorphism of the additive group $\mathbb{R}$ into the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. Conversely, any homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to the multiplicative group $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ provides a solution to the functional equations we're dealing with, by taking the real and imaginary parts for $g$ and $f$ respectively.

Let $\varphi\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a field automorphism. Consider the map
$$
\psi\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C},\qquad 
\psi(x)=\varphi(e^x).
$$
Then $\psi$ is a homomorphism of the additive group of $\mathbb{R}$ into the group $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$.

Let's take as $\varphi$ an automorphism that doesn't send the reals into the reals; the existence of such automorphisms was first proved as a consequence of Steinitz's theorem by Segre (Atti dell'Accademia dei Lincei, 1947). Of course, this requires the axiom of choice. Basically, an automorphism is defined by an arbitrary permutation of a transcendency basis of $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. It's sufficient to send a real element (we can always assume one is present, say $e$) into a non real one (which of course must exist).

By Theorem 2 in a paper by [Kestelman (Proc. London Math. Soc. (2), 1951)](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Kestelman51.pdf), the image of the reals under such an automorphism is dense in the complex numbers; since
$$
\phi(\mathbb{R})=\psi(\mathbb{R})\cup\{0\}\cup(-\psi(\mathbb{R})),
$$
also $\psi(\mathbb{R})$ must be dense in $\mathbb{C}$, so it can't be contained in the unit circle and so $\psi$ has not the form $\psi(x)=\cos(ax)+i\sin(ax)$, for any real $a$.

Comment: I did not understand your last sentence. In fact, $\psi$ DOES NOT have to be of that form, as I explain in the updated version of the question.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis This is another way to build discontinuous solutions to the equations, because continuous ones do have that form.